# I am getting the equation of Downward parabola as x^2=4ay ???

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

---

### Downward Parabola

I wanted to find the simple equation of parabola having vertex at origin of coordinate axes And facing downwards$~(-y)~$

---

So, **focus would be $~(-a,0)~$**

---

**equation of diretix would be $~(y=a)~$**

---

As **e=1 for a parabola**
[parabola](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYC1Y.png)
As i proceeded

[image]

Please help me where I went wrong????

Comment: $$(h+a)^2+k^2=(k-a)^2$$ right?

Comment: Please write an *informative* title—one that will help others find the problem and its solution.

Comment: 1) Rewrite title as "Error in parabola equation with origin as focus" or some such. 2) The x-coordinate of origin is 0,  you took $a$. 3) Right hand side should be $ (-y+a)^2$ with proper sign when you want a parabola lying below x-axis. 4) Check if you get $y= (a^2-x^2)/(....)$.

Answer (score 0):

Downward facing parabola would have focus as $(0,-a)$ and directrix as $y=a$.
$$SP^2=PM^2$$
$${\sqrt {(x-0)^2+(y+a)^2}}=|y-a|$$
$${(x-0)^2+(y+a)^2}=(y-a)^2$$
$$x^2+y^2+a^2+2ay=y^2+a^2-2ay$$
$$x^2=-4ay$$

Comment: but how can Point P have +y?? it can have either (x,-y) or (-x,-y) as coordinates as its facing downwords. Il we apply distance formula for sp and square it we have x^2 + (--y+a)^2

Comment: $y$ can be negative but you substitute it as $+y$ only. Do not change the signs based on the quadrant.

Comment: is there some reason why your statement is right?